# TimeSpan adding minutes to zero hour

Tags: c#, timespan

I'm adding time span with interval size(suppose one minute) in a loop and whenever it gets 23:59 and at this point I'm trying to add one minute, it giving me result 1.00:00:00:00 something like this. How can i get continuous adding intervals when it comes 23:59:00 like

```
00:00:00
00:01:00
00:02:00
```

Thanks.

Comment: "23 hours and 59 minutes" plus "one minute" is "one day". What's the problem?

Comment: i don't understand your question. you are adding one minute after another. and finally it get's one day.

Comment: You want to truncate on just the hour,minute, and seconds part, or at least for displaying. Just do the following `ts.ToString("hh:mm:ss")`.

Comment: @nag, your question is not clear. Are you wanting to have a loop that will add 1 minute onto a timespan until the timespan reaches 23 hours 59 minutes?

Comment: @Kane Yes after it reaches 23.59 i want 00:00:00 like kind of this without 1 day is this time span helps me on that or any other i need to change?

Comment: What are you using the TimeSpan for?  Are you actually using the values, or just using it for display?

Comment: Yeah i'm using these time span values in binding to list.

Comment: @nag - what does that mean?  Are you using the actual values in the list, or are you just creating a list of displayed values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either

- When displaying your timespan, ignore the days part:

```
string toDisplay = yourTimeSpan.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

- After incrementing your timespan, subtract a day if it is a day or longer:

```
if (yourTimeSpan.Days == 1)
  yourTimeSpan = yourTimeSpan.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));

// or Wonko the Sane's improved version
if (yourTimeSpan.Days > 0) yourTimeSpan = new TimeSpan();
```

Comment: Or, `if (yourTimeSpan.Days > 0) yourTimeSpan = new TimeSpan();`

Comment: So it still continues 00:00:01 02 03... with day 1.00

Comment: @nag In the first case, the `day` part does keep incrementing, you just don't show it. In the second case, it zeroes out the day part when it hits 1.

Comment: @Wonko That's much better... (With mine I was worried about if you might not hit one day exactly, but in this case it shouldn't happen.)

Comment: Too late - I had already +1'ed ya.  :)

Comment: Thank you so much Rawling and Wonko.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your TimeSpan gets over one day, it will format itself in ToString() adding that day to returned string. You could either format ToString() or substract one day after you accumulate it. If you would like your TimeSpan not to go over one day, check this code:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
TimeSpan day = dt.AddDays(1) - dt;
TimeSpan minute = dt.AddMinutes(1) - dt;

for (int i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
{
     ts = ts.Add(minute);
     if (ts.TotalDays > 1)
     {
         ts = ts.Subtract(day);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're printing out the value of your TimeSpan just using the standard toString() method? this will yield the TimeSpan in a "human formatted" time representation, e.g. 25 hours will be 1 day and 1 hour.

If you want to get the total number of minutes, for example use the [TimeSpan.TotalMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes.aspx) proprety

Answer (score 0):

You want it to loop back to 00:00 after reaching 23:59?

In your loop, or wherever you're trying to achieve this, check if the Days component is bigger than 0, and if so, subtract one day.

Seems too simple an aswer to be right... what do you really look for?

Comment: Yes i want to loop back to 00:00 after 23.59

Answer (score 0):

After your `TimeSpan` reaches more than a day, you'll get that form of output. If you still want to show it in hour form, try something like

```
String.format({0}:{1}:{2}, span.Days*24 + span.Hours, span.Minutes, span.Seconds)
```